# Правильная реализация enum в java

Tags: java, enum

В учебных целях делаю приложение которое собирает `строку (банковский счёт)` из разных значений согласно этой [таблице](http://www.profbanking.com/info/835-chart-of-accounts-in-banks.html) первые 3 символа счёта я беру из первого enum:

```
 public enum FirstPrimaryCode {
    DEBIT("408"),
    ACCUM("423"),
    CREDIT("454"),
    BANK("474");

    private final String code;

    FirstPrimaryCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

> Для 2ух последующих цифр кода мне пришлось сделать 4 разных `enum`,
>   так как на разных типов счетов есть совпадающий код имеющий разные
>   назначения.

```
public enum AccumSecondaryCode {
    ON_DEMAND("01"),
    UP_TO_ONE_YEAR("05"),
    UP_TO_THREE_YEARS("06"),
    MORE_THREE_YEARS("07");

    private final String code;

    AccumSecondaryCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}


public enum CreditSecondaryCode {
    UP_TO_ONE_YEAR("04"),
    UP_TO_THREE_YEARS("05"),
    MORE_THREE_YEARS("06");

    private final String code;

    CreditSecondaryCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

> В этих 2ух `enam` можно увидеть совпадающий код, которые принадлежит к разным назначениям счетов.

Подскажите как правильней реализовать данную операцию, конечно в моих масштабах достаточно и такой реализации, но всё-же хотелось бы разобраться в этом вопросе.

Comment: можно написать что-то такое: https://ideone.com/JbVRnE . Компилятор не даст вызвать `createAccount` с неправильным сочетанием кодов

Comment: @zRrr, Спасибо, попробую разобраться в вашем коде добавив в него все свои данные.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется енамы тут немного неправильно применены. Мне в голову приходит примерная такая идея

```
class FirstPrimaryCode {
    public static Debit debit() {
        return new Debit("408");
    }
    public static Accum accum() {
        return new Accum("423");
    }
    // другие методы
}


class Debit {
    private StringBuilder code;

    public Debit(String code) {
        this.code = new StringBuilder(code);
    }

    public DebitSecondaryCode onDemand() {
        code.append("01");
        return new DebitSecondaryCode(code);
    }
    public DebitSecondaryCode upToOneYear() {
        code.append("05");
        return new DebitSecondaryCode(code);
    }
}

class Accum {
    private StringBuilder code;
    public Accum(String code) {
        this.code = new StringBuilder(code);
    }

    public AccumSecondaryCode upToOneYear() {
        code.append("04");
        return new AccumSecondaryCode(code);
    }
}



class DebitSecondaryCode {
    private StringBuilder code;

    public DebitSecondaryCode(StringBuilder code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

class AccumSecondaryCode {
    private StringBuilder code;

    public AccumSecondaryCode(StringBuilder code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

То есть, созданы классы держатели кода и каждый вызванный метод будет добавлять новые числа к коду. Составить нужную строку потом можно будет примерно таким образом

```
FirstPrimaryCode
    .debit()
    .onDemand()
    .thirdStep
    .fourthStep
    .get();
```

На последнем этапе должен возвращаться объект реализующий какой-то интерфейс *Code*, где будет реализован метод *get*.
Поскольку каждый этап реализован в виде класса,то вызвать неправильный метод невозможно. Нельзя вызвать дважды *debit()* или *acuum* и потом *onDemand* и нельзя вручную его редактировать.
Может и не то что вам надо, но как вариант прошу рассмотреть

Comment: Енамы я выбрал, просто как первый способ, чтобы реализовать, возможно вы правы, и стоит другим способом это реализовать. Потому что если посмотреть таблицу формирования счетов, то наверное голова лопнет, если это все енамами организовывать.